# Vanilla JS Alarm Clock: Scope and Increment Questions

Tags: javascript, scope

I have 2 issues with my alarm clock.

1)When the hour is increased or decreased to over 12, I want to switch from AM to PM. The problem is that where I call the today.getHours();, it's inside a different function. My increment button function (to increase/decrease) is outside that function and when moved inside the clock function holding today.getHours(), doesn't work, so I can't say when hours is greater than 12, switch to PM. And it seems redundant to call getHours again. Does anyone have any recommendations on how to fix this in vanilla JS? Is there a better way to do it?

2)When clicked, the minute decrease increment button gives negative values. I know this probably has a simple solution but I think I've been staring at it for too long to see it.

```js
//Select Elements
const alarm_time = document.getElementById('alarmTime');
const set_alarm = document.getElementById('setAlarm');
const alarm_alert = document.getElementById('alarmAlert');
const hr_increase= document.getElementById('hourIncrease');
const hr_decrease = document.getElementById('hourDecrease');
const min_increase= document.getElementById('minuteIncrease');
const min_decrease = document.getElementById('minuteDecrease');
const increment = document.querySelectorAll('.increment');

//Variables
let hr;
let min;
let TOD;
let alarmHr=0;
let alarmMin=0;
let alarmTOD="AM";
let alarmActive=false;

//Alarm Sound
let sound = new Audio("https://res.cloudinary.com/saveallthethings/video/upload/v1565033348/Free%20Music%20Downloads/bensound-hey_vunrwo.mp3");

//Alarm Function
if (alarmHr== hr && parseInt(alarmMin) == min && alarmTOD == TOD){
    sound.play();
    card.classList.add("blinkingAlarm");
}

//Get Time
function clock(){
  //Display Greeting, Time and Date
  let today = new Date();
  let year = today.getFullYear();
  let date = today.getDate();
  let hours = today.getHours(); 
  let minutes = today.getMinutes();

  //Specify Am or PM, and populate greeting
  if (hours >= 17){
    timeofDay = "PM";
  } else if (hours >= 12 && hours < 17){
    timeofDay = "PM";
  } else {
    timeofDay = " AM";
  }

  //Convert Hours to 12hr Format
  if (hours>12){
    hours = hours - 12;
  }
  else if (hours===0){
    hours = 12; 
  }
  
  //For single digit minutes, add a zero 
  if (minutes<10){
    minutes = "0" + minutes;
  }
  else {
    minutes = minutes;
  }
  
  if (alarm_time.classList.contains("blinkingText")){
    alarm_time.innerHTML = (alarmHr + ":" + alarmMin + alarmTOD);
    }else{alarm_time.innerHTML = (hours + ":" + minutes + timeofDay);}

}//Closing Brackets for clock fnc

//Set Interval to Update Time
setInterval('clock()', 500);

//Count Clicks on Set Alarm Btn
let clickCounter = 0;
set_alarm.onclick = function() {
  clickCounter += 1;
  //Second Click sets the alarm, says "Alarm set to"
    if((clickCounter % 2) === 0){
    alarm_time.classList.remove("blinkingText");
    alarmActive = true;  
    if (alarmHr == 0 && alarmMin == 0){
      alarm_alert.innerHTML = "no alarm set";
    }else{
      alarm_alert.innerHTML = "alarm set for  "+  alarmHr +":" + alarmMin + alarmTOD;
    }
    //Loop that disables and hides buttons
    for (var i = 0; i < increment.length; i++) {
      hourIncrease.classList.remove("visibility");
      hourDecrease.classList.remove("visibility");
      minuteIncrease.classList.remove("visibility");
      minuteDecrease.classList.remove("visibility");
      document.getElementById("hourIncrease").disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("hourDecrease").disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("minuteIncrease").disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("minuteDecrease").disabled = true;
        }                    
    } else {
        alarm_time.classList.add("blinkingText");
        //Loop Over the Node List for increment
        for (var i = 0; i < increment.length; i++) {
          hourIncrease.classList.add("visibility");
          hourDecrease.classList.add("visibility");
          minuteIncrease.classList.add("visibility");
          minuteDecrease.classList.add("visibility");
          document.getElementById("hourIncrease").disabled = false;
          document.getElementById("hourDecrease").disabled = false;
          document.getElementById("minuteIncrease").disabled = false;
          document.getElementById("minuteDecrease").disabled = false;
        }                        
    }
  };

//Turn off alarm
dismiss.onclick = function() {
  if(alarmActive = "true"){
    alarmActive ="false"
    alarmHr = 0;
    alarmMin = 0;
    alarmTOD = "AM";   
    alarm_alert.innerHTML = "no alarm set";
    sound.pause();
    alarm_time.classList.remove("blinkingText");
    //Loop that disables and hides buttons
    for (var i = 0; i < increment.length; i++) {
      hourIncrease.classList.remove("visibility");
      hourDecrease.classList.remove("visibility");
      minuteIncrease.classList.remove("visibility");
      minuteDecrease.classList.remove("visibility");
      document.getElementById("hourIncrease").disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("hourDecrease").disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("minuteIncrease").disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("minuteDecrease").disabled = true;
        }                        
  }
};

hr_increase.onclick = function() { 
  alarmHr++;
  if (alarmHr > 12){
    alarmHr= alarmHr - 12;
  }
}

hr_decrease.onclick = function() { 
  alarmHr--;
  if (alarmHr <= 0){
    alarmHr= alarmHr + 12;
  }
  console.log(alarmHr);}; 

min_increase.onclick = function() { 
  alarmMin++;
  if (alarmMin < 10){
      alarmMin= "0" + alarmMin;
    }
  if(alarmMin > 59){
    alarmMin= alarmMin-60 ;
  }
  if(alarmMin == 0){
    alarmMin= "00";
  }

}

min_decrease.onclick = function() { 
  alarmMin--;
  if (alarmMin < 10){
    alarmMin= "0" + minutes;
  }
  if (alarmMin < 0){
    alarmMin= alarmMin % 60;
  }
  };
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:900|Open+Sans:800|Source+Sans+Pro:300');


html, body {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size:15px;
}

.card_container{
  height:100vh;
}
.center{
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
}

.card{
  border-radius:15px;
  background-color: rgba(254, 253, 253,0.8);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 51px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.13);
  max-width:22rem;
  border:solid rgba(254, 253, 253,0.8) 0.1px;
}

.blinkingAlarm{
  animation:blinkingAlarm 1.2s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes blinkingAlarm{
      50%{
           border:solid white 7px;}
 }

.card_inner{
  border-radius:15px;
  margin:.75rem;
}


.card_currentContainer{
  border-radius:15px;
  margin-bottom:1rem;
}

.card_alarmContainer {
  color:#7E7E7E;
  background:#fff;
  text-align:center;
}


.card_alarmContainer{
   flex-direction:column;
   border-radius:15px;
}

.alarmOptions{
  display:flex;
  color:#7E7E7E;
  padding-top:.5rem;
  padding-bottom:.5rem;
}

.blinkingText{
  animation:blinkingText 1.6s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes blinkingText{
      50%{opacity:0.3;}
}

.setBox{
  flex-direction:column;
  padding-left:.5rem;
  padding-right:.5rem;
  padding-top:0;
}

.button {
  display:block;
  border-style:none;
  margin: 0px 0px;
  padding:0px;
}

.increment{
  font-size:1rem;
  border:none;
  background: rgba(254, 253, 253,0.8);
  color:#7E7E7E;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
  visibility:hidden;
}

.increment:hover{
  cursor:pointer;
  color:black;
  border-style:none;
}

.visibility{
  visibility:visible;
}
.alarmBox{
  padding-bottom:.2rem;
}

.alarmTime{

  font-size:2rem;
  line-height:1rem;
  padding-top:.7rem;
}

.alarmAlert{
  font-size:.8rem;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  padding-top:.5rem;
}

.card_buttonsContainer{
  width:100%;
  margin:1rem 0rem;
  justify-content:space-between;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.btn{
  height:3rem;
  width:8rem;
}

#setAlarm{
  transition: .2s;
  color:#fff; 
  cursor:pointer; 
  border-radius:15px;
    background: linear-gradient(to left, #ff7e5f , #feb47b); 
  padding-right:.5rem;
  padding-left:.5rem;
  font-size:1.5rem; 
  margin-right:0.3rem;
}

#setAlarm:hover{
  border-radius:20px;
  opacity: .8;
}

#dismiss{
  transition: .2s;
  font-size:1.5rem; 
  color:#fff; 
  border-radius:15px; 
  cursor:pointer; 
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #64B1F2 , #00DBF3); 
  padding-right:.5rem;
  padding-left:.5rem;
  margin-left:0.3rem;
}

#dismiss:hover{
  border-radius:20px;
  opacity: .8;
}

/***Media Queries****/
@media only screen and (max-width:332px) {
  .current_greetings{
    text-align:center;
  }
  .card_buttonsContainer{
     justify-content:center;
  }
  .btn{
    margin-bottom:.5rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="card_container center">  
  <div class ="card">
    <div class="card_inner">
      <div class="card_alarmContainer center"> 
        <div class="alarmOptions ">
          <div class="setBox center">
            <button class="increment center" id="hourIncrease" disabled>&#x2b;</button>
            <button class="increment center" id="hourDecrease" disabled>&#x2212;</button>
          </div>
          <div class="alarmBox">
          <div class="alarmTime center" id="alarmTime"></div>
          <div class="alarmAlert" id="alarmAlert">no alarm set</div>
            </div>
          <div class="setBox center">
            <button class="increment center" id="minuteIncrease" disabled>&#x2b;</button>
            <button class="increment center" id="minuteDecrease" disabled>&#x2212;</button>
          </div>
          
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card_buttonsContainer center">
        <div class ="buttonBox center">
          <div class="btn center" id="setAlarm">Set Alarm</div>
        </div>
        <div class ="buttonBox center">
          <div class="btn center" id="dismiss">Dismiss</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! In the future, please include all the relevant code related to your question, right here in your question, rather than linking to executable versions of your code at third party sites as those links can die over time. You can create an executable code snippet in your question by clicking the "code snippet" button `<>` while composing or editing your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you need to increase and decrease the hour on the minute change. I also suggest pulling the hour increase and hour decrease out into functions (I have sample code of a working solution) so you can use them in the minute increase and decrease functions to increase or decrease the time. I also suggest using a function for the alarm time of day change so you can use it in both your hour increase and hour decrease functions. Your initial value for alarm hour was 0 but there is no 0 hour. I suggest starting with 12 for the alarm hour. I updated all of this in my sample code

The way you can update the TOD is in the hour increase check if the new hour is 12 and then toggle the TOD. In the decrease you check if the new hour is 11 and then toggle the TOD. See my sample working code!

```js
//Select Elements
const alarm_time = document.getElementById('alarmTime');
const set_alarm = document.getElementById('setAlarm');
const alarm_alert = document.getElementById('alarmAlert');
const hr_increase= document.getElementById('hourIncrease');
const hr_decrease = document.getElementById('hourDecrease');
const min_increase= document.getElementById('minuteIncrease');
const min_decrease = document.getElementById('minuteDecrease');
const increment = document.querySelectorAll('.increment');

//Variables
let hr;
let min;
let TOD;
let alarmHr=12;
let alarmMin=0;
let alarmTOD="AM";
let alarmActive=false;

//Alarm Sound
let sound = new Audio("https://res.cloudinary.com/saveallthethings/video/upload/v1565033348/Free%20Music%20Downloads/bensound-hey_vunrwo.mp3");

//Alarm Function
if (alarmHr== hr && parseInt(alarmMin) == min && alarmTOD == TOD){
    sound.play();
    card.classList.add("blinkingAlarm");
}

function toggleAlarmTOD() {
  if(alarmTOD === "AM") {
     alarmTOD = "PM"
  } else {
     alarmTOD = "AM"
  }
}

function increaseHr() {
  alarmHr++;
  if(alarmHr === 12) {
    toggleAlarmTOD();
  } else if (alarmHr > 12){
    alarmHr = alarmHr - 12;
  }
}

function decreaseHr() {
  alarmHr--;
  if(alarmHr <= 0) {
    alarmHr = alarmHr + 12;
  } else if(alarmHr === 11) {
    toggleAlarmTOD();
  }
}

//Get Time
function clock(){
  //Display Greeting, Time and Date
  let today = new Date();
  let year = today.getFullYear();
  let date = today.getDate();
  let hours = today.getHours(); 
  let minutes = today.getMinutes();

  //Specify Am or PM, and populate greeting
  if(hours >= 12){
    timeofDay = "PM";
  } else {
    timeofDay = " AM";
  }

  //Convert Hours to 12hr Format
  if (hours>12){
    hours = hours - 12;
  }
  else if (hours===0){
    hours = 12; 
  }
  
  //For single digit minutes, add a zero 
  if (minutes < 10) {
    minutes = "0" + minutes;
  }
  else {
    minutes = minutes;
  }
  
  if (alarm_time.classList.contains("blinkingText")){
    alarm_time.innerHTML = (alarmHr + ":" + (alarmMin < 10 ? "0" + alarmMin : alarmMin) + alarmTOD);
    }else{alarm_time.innerHTML = (hours + ":" + minutes + timeofDay);}

}//Closing Brackets for clock fnc

//Set Interval to Update Time
setInterval('clock()', 500);

//Count Clicks on Set Alarm Btn
let clickCounter = 0;
set_alarm.onclick = function() {
  clickCounter++;
  //Second Click sets the alarm, says "Alarm set to"
    if((clickCounter % 2) === 0){
    alarm_time.classList.remove("blinkingText");
    alarmActive = true;  
    if (alarmHr == 0 && alarmMin == 0){
      alarm_alert.innerHTML = "no alarm set";
    }else{
      alarm_alert.innerHTML = "alarm set for  " + alarmHr + ":" + (alarmMin < 10 ? "0" + alarmMin : alarmMin) + alarmTOD;
    }
    //Loop that disables and hides buttons
    for (var i = 0; i < increment.length; i++) {
      hourIncrease.classList.remove("visibility");
      hourDecrease.classList.remove("visibility");
      minuteIncrease.classList.remove("visibility");
      minuteDecrease.classList.remove("visibility");
      document.getElementById("hourIncrease").disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("hourDecrease").disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("minuteIncrease").disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("minuteDecrease").disabled = true;
        }                    
    } else {
        alarm_time.classList.add("blinkingText");
        //Loop Over the Node List for increment
        for (var i = 0; i < increment.length; i++) {
          hourIncrease.classList.add("visibility");
          hourDecrease.classList.add("visibility");
          minuteIncrease.classList.add("visibility");
          minuteDecrease.classList.add("visibility");
          document.getElementById("hourIncrease").disabled = false;
          document.getElementById("hourDecrease").disabled = false;
          document.getElementById("minuteIncrease").disabled = false;
          document.getElementById("minuteDecrease").disabled = false;
        }                        
    }
  };

//Turn off alarm
dismiss.onclick = function() {
  if(alarmActive = "true") {
    alarmActive ="false"
    alarmHr = 12;
    alarmMin = 0;
    alarmTOD = "AM";   
    alarm_alert.innerHTML = "no alarm set";
    sound.pause();
    alarm_time.classList.remove("blinkingText");
    //Loop that disables and hides buttons
    for (var i = 0; i < increment.length; i++) {
      hourIncrease.classList.remove("visibility");
      hourDecrease.classList.remove("visibility");
      minuteIncrease.classList.remove("visibility");
      minuteDecrease.classList.remove("visibility");
      document.getElementById("hourIncrease").disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("hourDecrease").disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("minuteIncrease").disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("minuteDecrease").disabled = true;
        }                        
  }
};

hr_increase.onclick = function() { 
  increaseHr();
}

hr_decrease.onclick = function() { 
  decreaseHr();
}; 

min_increase.onclick = function() { 
  alarmMin++;
  if(alarmMin > 59){
    alarmMin = 0;
    increaseHr();
  }
}

min_decrease.onclick = function() { 
  alarmMin--;
  if (alarmMin < 0){
    alarmMin = 59;
    decreaseHr();
  }
};
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:900|Open+Sans:800|Source+Sans+Pro:300');


html, body {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size:15px;
}

.card_container{
  height:100vh;
}
.center{
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
}

.card{
  border-radius:15px;
  background-color: rgba(254, 253, 253,0.8);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 51px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.13);
  max-width:22rem;
  border:solid rgba(254, 253, 253,0.8) 0.1px;
}

.blinkingAlarm{
  animation:blinkingAlarm 1.2s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes blinkingAlarm{
      50%{
           border:solid white 7px;}
 }

.card_inner{
  border-radius:15px;
  margin:.75rem;
}


.card_currentContainer{
  border-radius:15px;
  margin-bottom:1rem;
}

.card_alarmContainer {
  color:#7E7E7E;
  background:#fff;
  text-align:center;
}


.card_alarmContainer{
   flex-direction:column;
   border-radius:15px;
}

.alarmOptions{
  display:flex;
  color:#7E7E7E;
  padding-top:.5rem;
  padding-bottom:.5rem;
}

.blinkingText{
  animation:blinkingText 1.6s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes blinkingText{
      50%{opacity:0.3;}
}

.setBox{
  flex-direction:column;
  padding-left:.5rem;
  padding-right:.5rem;
  padding-top:0;
}

.button {
  display:block;
  border-style:none;
  margin: 0px 0px;
  padding:0px;
}

.increment{
  font-size:1rem;
  border:none;
  background: rgba(254, 253, 253,0.8);
  color:#7E7E7E;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
  visibility:hidden;
}

.increment:hover{
  cursor:pointer;
  color:black;
  border-style:none;
}

.visibility{
  visibility:visible;
}
.alarmBox{
  padding-bottom:.2rem;
}

.alarmTime{

  font-size:2rem;
  line-height:1rem;
  padding-top:.7rem;
}

.alarmAlert{
  font-size:.8rem;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  padding-top:.5rem;
}

.card_buttonsContainer{
  width:100%;
  margin:1rem 0rem;
  justify-content:space-between;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.btn{
  height:3rem;
  width:8rem;
}

#setAlarm{
  transition: .2s;
  color:#fff; 
  cursor:pointer; 
  border-radius:15px;
    background: linear-gradient(to left, #ff7e5f , #feb47b); 
  padding-right:.5rem;
  padding-left:.5rem;
  font-size:1.5rem; 
  margin-right:0.3rem;
}

#setAlarm:hover{
  border-radius:20px;
  opacity: .8;
}

#dismiss{
  transition: .2s;
  font-size:1.5rem; 
  color:#fff; 
  border-radius:15px; 
  cursor:pointer; 
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #64B1F2 , #00DBF3); 
  padding-right:.5rem;
  padding-left:.5rem;
  margin-left:0.3rem;
}

#dismiss:hover{
  border-radius:20px;
  opacity: .8;
}

/***Media Queries****/
@media only screen and (max-width:332px) {
  .current_greetings{
    text-align:center;
  }
  .card_buttonsContainer{
     justify-content:center;
  }
  .btn{
    margin-bottom:.5rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="card_container center">  
  <div class ="card">
    <div class="card_inner">
      <div class="card_alarmContainer center"> 
        <div class="alarmOptions ">
          <div class="setBox center">
            <button class="increment center" id="hourIncrease" disabled>&#x2b;</button>
            <button class="increment center" id="hourDecrease" disabled>&#x2212;</button>
          </div>
          <div class="alarmBox">
          <div class="alarmTime center" id="alarmTime"></div>
          <div class="alarmAlert" id="alarmAlert">no alarm set</div>
            </div>
          <div class="setBox center">
            <button class="increment center" id="minuteIncrease" disabled>&#x2b;</button>
            <button class="increment center" id="minuteDecrease" disabled>&#x2212;</button>
          </div>
          
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card_buttonsContainer center">
        <div class ="buttonBox center">
          <div class="btn center" id="setAlarm">Set Alarm</div>
        </div>
        <div class ="buttonBox center">
          <div class="btn center" id="dismiss">Dismiss</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```